# Excel: If two cells are the same, subtract from two different cells

Tags: excel, formula

I'm not a programmer and very new to excel so i'm having some trouble figuring this out.

In sheet1 I have columns, Lot Number (Column F), Stock Quantity (Column O) and Remaining Stock (Column Q).

In sheet3 I have Lot Number (Column D), and Amount Used (Column E)

Is there a formula that could look at the Lot Number column from both sheets and if they match, subtract Amount Used from Stock Quantity in the column, Remaining Stock?

Comment: Take a look at VLOOKUP

Comment: You can reference a different sheet by writing "sheetname!A9". If you always know in which columns you have to search you can then use a normal "If" to see if the values match and do your computation.

Answer (score 0):

For checking if two values are the same you can use the IF-Statement in a column.

```
=IF(A1 = 1, Yes, No)
```

For more Information about IF-Statement in excel look [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IF-function-69aed7c9-4e8a-4755-a9bc-aa8bbff73be2)!

To reference a value of another sheet you can use a syntax like:

```
Sheet1!A1
```

For more information about references: [link](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-or-change-a-cell-reference-c7b8b95d-c594-4488-947e-c835903cebaa)

For your example:

```
=IF(Sheet1!F1 = Sheet3!D1, Sheet1!O1 - Sheet3!E1, 0)
```

EDIT:

removed

Comment: Sorry, ive corrected my answer.. For sure it should be `!` for reference to another sheet...

Comment: It would be placed to the Q1 cell for example. It would be the cell where you want to have the value of Remaining Stock.

Answer (score 0):

Try this formula =IFERROR(O2-VLOOKUP(F2,Sheet3!D:E,2,0),""). I assumed the Lot Number is unique. I assumed the data are exactly on the sheets and columns you have mentioned.

Comment: This worked for the first one. The thing is that in sheet 3 the (same) lot number may be repeated with a new amount used. So sheet one the lot number / stock quantity will only be listed once, while in sheet 3 it can be listed multiple times with different amounts used until our stock is 0.

Comment: Then a SUMIF should resolve the problem is you won't change the Lot number and Stock Quantity in Sheet 1    =O2-SUMIF(Sheet3!D:D,Sheet1!F2,Sheet3!E:E)

Comment: I amended the formula `=O2-SUMIF(Sheet3!E:E,VLOOKUP(F2,Sheet3!D:E,2,FALSE))`. This should work better

Comment: =O2-SUMIF(Sheet3!D:D,Sheet1!F2,Sheet3!E:E) This actually ended up working beautifully. You're literally jesus. Thank you!!